# Addlistener function regarding the Leap Motion

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, leap-motion

I've been trying to gather tracking data using the Leap Motion in C# with Visual Studio 2013.

I used a video to help as a guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5O2Un1pVj8w) and used the official Leap website as well (https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/v2/csharp/devguide/Project_Setup.html).

Upon completion of the aforementioned video, I keep getting an error regarding my Addlistener function and my listener variable. The error states that the  "type or namespace name 'listener' could not be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, **are you missing a directive or assembly reference?**

Comment: Honestly, how do I figure that out?

Comment: Well when you're using external libraries, you need to reference them by adding it via the IDE. And then you need to import the namespace(s) that are relevant.

Comment: I did correctly import the namespace I intended on using.  I did type in "using Leap" before it though, thinking that the Addlistener function originated from that particular library.